# Suppose $F(x):=\begin{cases} f(x)& x\in I\\0& x\not\in I\end{cases}$ then $F$ is piecewise constant on $J$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ a piecewise constant function on the bounded interval $I$, $I\subseteq J$ a bounded interval, $F:J\to \mathbb{R}$ $F(x):=\begin{cases} f(x)& x\in I\\0& x\not\in I\end{cases}$ then $F$ is piecewise constant on $J$ and $p.c\int_{J}F=p.c\int_I f$

So the way a piecewise constant integral has been defined is that a function is piecewise constant on an interval $I$ if there exists a partition $P$, such that $f$ is piecewise constant with respect to $P$.

Then the piecewise constant integral, $p.c\int_{[P]}F=\sum_{K\in P}c_K\vert K\vert$ where $c_K$ is the value of $F$ on $K$.

So if I have a partition $P$ of $F$ for interval $J$, then I think it's clear that $P'=\{ K\in P: K\cap I\}$ is a partition of $I$ as none of intervals will intersect since $P$ is a partition, and $P'$ will cover $I$ since $P$ covers $J\supseteq I$.

So then I want to say that similarly $J\setminus I$ will be a union of at most $2$ intervals $A,B$ which can be covered by $P''=\{K\in P: K\cap A\}$ and $P'''={K\in P: K\cap B}$$

Then $P'\cup P''\cup P'''$ is a partition of $J$. Since $K\cap X\subseteq K$ for any set $X$

Then $c_k=c_{k\cap X}$ for any interval $X$.

Thus $\sum_{K\in P}C_K\vert K\vert =\sum_{N\in P''} C_N\vert N\vert +\sum_{M \in P'}C_M\vert M\vert+\sum+{O\in P'''}C_O\vert O\vert $

But $F$ is $0$ on $A,B$ thus $C_K=0$ for all intervals in $P''$ and $P'''$.

Thus $p.c\int_J F=\sum_{M\in P'}C_M\vert M\vert=p.c\int_I f$ since $P'$ is a partition of $I$ and $f(x)=F(x)$ for each interval in $P'$

Does this work? I think I can justify that $J\setminus I$ is at most $2$ intervals by $J=[a,b]$, $I=[c,d]$ for some $a\leq c\leq d\leq b$. Thus $J\setminus I=[a,c)\cup (d,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works. Partitionning is a very good idea.

I think you can also see the things as follow and as you mention:

$f$ being piecewise on $I$ and because all interval are convex in $\mathbb{R}$.

Without loss of generality, we can write $I$ as follow

$$ I=[a,b] \subseteq J $$

Where $J$ can be written always without loss of generality (turn a $[$ into a $]$)

$$ J= [c,d] \cup  [a,b] \cup [e,f]$$

So you get the fact that :

$$ F (x)= \begin{cases} 0  , x\in[c,d] \\f(x) , x\in I=[a,b] \\0 , x\in [g,h] \end{cases} $$

$$ \int_J F = \int_I f $$ with that.

Written like this $F$ is piecewise constant on $J$ because $f$ is on $I$.

I hope it helps you.